# How to make a server for a Java and MySQL application

Tags: java, mysql, server, desktop-application

I created a Java application that accesses a **MySQL database** (made using **MySQL Workbench**). I want to create an installer for my application so that other users can use it on other computers, but I can't figure out how to do so.

I tried using **Launch4j** and **Inno Setup Compiler**, but when I tried to install the application on another computer it didn't access my database.

After a bit of research, I found out that I (maybe?) have to use a server for my database, but I couldn't figure out what and how to do that.

**My questions are:**

> 1. Do I have to use a server to make my application installable on other computers?
> 2. What is the easiest server to use for this task?

PS: I'm very new at programming so please be as explicit as you can :)

Comment: If you are hosting the database yourself you would need to open up ports on your router to allow the connection/authentication to go through (This is typically not the solution). Or the user needs to have mysql installed and configured prior to your app from installing.

Comment: @locus2k Even if the user has mysql installed and configured, the data is not going to be consistent with different users. The is the intended behavior in certain cases, but not sure what this application here needs to achieve.

Comment: @BarathSankar that is true. OP could execute a set of sql scripts during install to make the starting set of data consistent across installs. Without know the end goal it is hard to know exactly what is needed.

Comment: @locus2k The question mentions something about the server, so I guess there is a need for data consistency.. Just guessing :P

Comment: @locus2k The goal is to create an application which will be installed (with just a setup file if possible, so the other users won't have to install MySQL on their computers) on multiple computers and every user has to have access to the same database.

Comment: If it is not too much work, you could use an **H2 database**, as you can embed that in your application itself without addition installing a database server application. H2 has a mysql compatibility modus. And you can use an SQL dump in MySQL with CREATE TABLEs. _Experiment first in small._

Comment: @Anna so that would require you to install mysql on a central computer that everyone can access on the network

Comment: @Anna will all users be within the same private network (i.e. LAN) (or have access to such via VPN) or be random people distributed across the public internet? Either way you need some central server (e.g. maybe a cloud service) for your database, but the exact topology will depend on the userbase.

Comment: Hello @Anna : Condidering that every user will have access to the same database (and share some datas), you definitely need to install a server (on the Web, or inside the Company). If so, I highly recommand to adopt an API/REST architecture. Install a Backend in Java/Spring on the server with your database, and adapt your client to make some REST call.

Comment: @Anna. I also need to answer the second question (What is the easiest server to use for this task?). I recommend to have free (or almost) server in the cloud using AWS, GCP or Azure. I personally use AWS. You will get a Linux server, and then you will have to install your database, and the JRE on this server. Then you will have to deploy your Java/Spring Backend application on this server.